# Соединение сервера на C++ с браузером через сокеты

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, winsock

Появилась мысль написать сервер на с++ используя библиотеку winsock и подключаться к нему с браузера. То есть фактически я хочу сделать сайт, но выдавать данные браузеру через сервер, который берет их с БД.
я слышал, что в js можно работать с веб-сокетами, но можно ли их соединить с сокетами winsock? Если да, то как?

Comment: Это возможно, но при чем тут JS я не понял. Готовое решение - https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/download

Comment: Вам надо будет реализовать протокол websocket. Но будет работать поверх TCP соединения, которое можно установить при помощи winsock

Comment: Например, я хочу перейти на другую страницу на сайте. Кликаю какую-то кнопку и получаю эту страницу(или другие данные для неё) с сервера. Но дело в том, что кроме js в браузере нечего использовать, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Что значит "поверх"? Если я правильно понял, вы имеете ввиду модель OSI. То есть если winsock работает на транспортном и сетевом уровнях, то websocket работает на прикладном? Как это всё соединить?

Comment: Сначала создаете соединение TCP, затем по этому соединению передаете данные в формате протокола websocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

websocket скорее всего просто не нужен в данном случае. Если хочется, что бы просто "можно было ходить по ссылкам", то все сильно проще.

Для начала сделайте обычный сервер, который случает 80 порт (хотя для отладки наверно лучше использовать 8080, но это дело такое). Сервер создается стандартным способом, через bind/listen/accept, все прямо по любому мануалу.

Когда браузер обратится к Вашему серверу (в адресной строке введете http://127.0.0.1/), на сервер в сокет прилетит что то вида

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

Там может ещё ряд полей прилететь, но все равно весь запрос завершаться двойным переводом строки (то есть в 0x13 0x10 0x13 0x10). А сами строки разделяются одинарным переводом.

Ок, запрос разобрать просто. Первое слово - это тип запроса. При "обычном гулянии по страницам" там GET. Всякие формочки обычно POST. Следующий слеш - это собственно хвост запроса - ресурс (если бы запросили http://127.0.0.1/index.html, там бы было /index.html). Браузеры присылают ресурс, который начинается с слеша, но если делать самому, то можно по разному. Остальное пока не важно.

Теперь нужно ответить клиенту. Тут чуточку сложнее

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 2

Hi
```

Сам ответ состоит из двух частей - заголовка и тела. Разбираем построчно

- вначале клиенту говорим, что мы также используем версию протокола 1.1 и все хорошо (код 200. OK - это текстовое представление). Если клиент прислал "плохой запрос, можно ему послать к примеру 404 - ресурс не найден), или 500 - серверу плохо:)
- дальше отвечаем именем хоста.
- потом пишем, что именно присылаем. У нас будет текст.
- также говорим, что соединение будет закрыто, после отправки запроса.
- а также сообщаем размер тела ответа. В принципе, если соединение закрывается, это не так важно, но лучше писать.
- а тут снова двойной перевод строки, что бы клиент знал, где что
- Собственно само тело запроса в два байта.

Все, этих знаний достаточно, что бы сделать простейший сервер.

Что почитать дальше?

- пример сервера https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-http-server-over-sockets/
- ещё один https://github.com/hckr/SimpleHTTP
- wikipedia - [http](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).

Comment: Соединение установил. Такой вопрос возник: у меня дома роутер. с ноутбука через вай-фай роутер могу подключиться к серверу на пк указывая ip, например, 192.168.0.2(пк с сервером). но как подключиться к нему с другой сети? при указании другого ip выходит окно со сменой пароля роутера.

Comment: А это уже избитый вопрос - называется проброс портов. Тут все сильно зависит от Вашего роутера и провайдера.